# Select text of a cell in a table on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jquery-3.5.1.
Google Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75
My html table has id="example".
I have a column in the table with class="myclass".

When I click a cell in that column of that table I want the whole text in just that cell to become highlighted... I mean, to become selected, so that it turns blue and I can copy and paste that text.

I tried this...

```
$("#example").on("mouseup", "td.myclass", function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    $(this).select();
});
```

The alert() fires but the cell text does not become highlighted.
If I comment out the alert() nothing happens at all. Not sure how to debug in Dev Tools

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the docs? `This event is limited to <input type="text"> fields and <textarea> boxes.`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Any hints about how to have the text of a <td> element be selected (highlighted in blue so you could copy and paste it) just by clicking on that cell?

Comment: No hints or suggestions about how to solve my problem? But you can criticize me.

Comment: How is pointing out what is stated in the docs considered criticism ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting texts in the table does not really require jQuery functionalities. You need to use the API in the `Selection` object.

```js
$("#example").on("mouseup", "td.myclass", function() {
    let range = new Range();
    range.setStart(this, 0);
    range.setEnd(this, this.childNodes.length);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="myclass">Cell 1</td>
      <td class="myclass">Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="myclass">Cell 3</td>
      <td class="myclass">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use can use `createRange` & `getSelection` api like this:

```
$("#example").on("mouseup", "td.myclass", function(e) {
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(e.target);
    getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    getSelection().addRange(range);
});
```